# How to wrap a "submit button" with GWT?

Tags: gwt

I am getting an error when I try to wrap a submit button with GWT:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Child cannot be null
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node$.isOrHasChild$(Node.java:278)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button.wrap(Button.java:55)
```

HTML Code:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <form id="login_form" action="javascript:;">
        <input id="username" type="text">
        <input id="password" type="password">
        <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
</div>
```

Java Code (GWT):

```
loginButton = Button.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("submit"));
```

Is there any way to wrap a submit button?

Comment: Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because your form is not connected to the DOM-Tree. Remove `display:none` from the surrounding `<div />` and it should work.

Comment: If I do this the login form is shown even before the whole gwt page is loaded.

Comment: How about calling Button.wrap() just after you make the form visible?